# Search Plus - How to skip an entry in mapping?

Tags: entries, plugin-searchplus

With the Search Plus plugin, it's possible to define a [custom mapping](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/searchplus/usage/hooks-events#addAlgoliaMapping) of your Entries for your Algolia index. This is basically a two-part process:

1. Call the `searchPlus_addAlgoliaMapping` to declare *which* function controls the mapping.
2. Write the function which controls the mapping.

I've done both of these, and it's working very well. Here's an example of my mapping function...

```php
return [
    'objectID' => $entry->id,
    'uri'      => $entry->uri,
    'title'    => $entry->title,
];
```

However, there are certain entries which should be **excluded** from the search index. My instinct tells me to simply wrap a conditional around that mapping, and return `false` (or `null`) for entries which should be excluded...

```php
if ($entry->includeInSearch) {
    return [
        'objectID' => $entry->id,
        'uri'      => $entry->uri,
        'title'    => $entry->title,
    ];
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The problem is, this seems to cause an error when Search Plus tries to export to Algolia...

[image: craft_searchplus_indexitem]

Which leads to the question: **What is the proper way to omit an entry from an Algolia index?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this, and I believe the trick was to return `true`.

UPDATE: Looks like this was fixed in version 1.5.2, returning false will skip the entry as expected.

Comment: Interesting... so you're saying I should return `true` instead of `false`? Seems counter-intuitive, but I'll give it a shot!